# Conditional joint probability

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, bayes-theorem

Suppose there are two random variables $\theta,Y$, which are dependent. Moreover, I  observe the value $f(\theta)=f$ for some known function $f(.)$ (which need not be invertible). I want to write the conditional probability $Pr(\theta=t|f(\theta)=f,Y=y)$ as a function of $Pr(Y=y|\theta=t)$.

Okay stop me when there is a mistake. Using Bayes' rule
$$Pr(\theta=t|f(\theta)=f,Y=y)=\frac{Pr(\theta=t)Pr(f(\theta)=f,Y=y|\theta=t)}{Pr(f(\theta)=f,Y=y)}.$$
My thinking is that we cannot simplify to
$$Pr(\theta=t|f(\theta)=f,Y=y)=\frac{Pr(\theta=t)Pr(f(\theta)=f|\theta=t)Pr(Y=y|\theta=t)}{Pr(f(\theta)=f)Pr(Y=y)}$$
since $f(\theta)$ and $y$ are not necessarily independent.

Is there another way to rewrite the "conditional joint probability" $Pr(f(\theta)=f,Y=y|\theta=t)$ as a function of $Pr(Y=y|\theta=t)$ using some law of iterated expectations, since I know $f(\theta)$ if given $\theta=t$?

Otherwise I can't straightforwadly apply the definition of joint probability here, since there is still a conditioning set. My attempt is
$$Pr(f(\theta)=f,Y=y|\theta=t)=E[Pr(f(\theta)=f,Y=y|\theta=t)|\theta=t]=E[Pr(f(\theta)=f,Y=y)|\theta=t]=E[Pr(Y=y|f(\theta)=f)Pr(f(\theta)=f)|\theta=t]=1\{f(\theta=t)=f\}E[Pr(Y=y|f(\theta)=f)|\theta=t]=1\{f(\theta=t)=f\}Pr(Y=y|\theta=t).$$
Is this correct? If not, is there another way to isolate $Pr(Y=y|\theta=t)$?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Given that $\theta = t$, the value of $f(\theta)$ is the constant $f(t)$.  So $$Pr[f(\theta)=f, Y=y|\theta = t]= Pr[Y=y|\theta=t]1\{f(t)=f\}$$ where $1\{f(t)=f\}$ is 1 if $f(t)=f$, and 0 else.

Comment: If you wanted, you could also just restrict the computation to cases when $f(t)=f$, since clearly $Pr[\theta=t|f(\theta)=f, Y=y]=0$ if $f(t)\neq f$.

Comment: Great, that's what I thought, thanks!